# Let Facebook user create posts on page, subject to moderation prior to going public

Tags: facebook, permissions

I'm the PAO (Public Affairs Officer) for our organization, and that means that I take the pictures and write the posts that go online.  However, the page owner wants to review my posts before making them public.  This could be as simple as only letting me post "private" posts, or something like that.  The main thing is that it has to be a permissions thing - i.e. it has to be *their* choice (not mine) what gets posted publicly. (That means it's scalable - the next PAO doesn't have to be an amazing writer, etc.)

They don't allow just anyone to post on the page.  They're very specific about reputation and all that.

Is there a way that they can allow a certain user to *write* the posts, but not *post* them (at least not in a way visible to the public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to publish any private posts in order to do what you want.
Let us have another look at your request though.

> Is there a way that they can allow a certain user to *write* the posts, but not *post* them (at least not in a way visible to the public)?

There are two parts to this question.

> ...allow a certain user to *write* the posts, but not *post* them...

If you mean that the user will be able to write a post but at the same time, systematically by Facebook, not allowed to publish the post, then there is *no simple way* to do what you ask for (maybe not even a way).

> ...(at least not in a way visible to the public)

**There is a very simple way to do this**.
It involves at least two parties working together as a "*team*".

- Someone with the role of `Admin` for the page acting as the "*Supervisor*" that will review and decide whether to approve the posts and publish them
- Someone assigned the role of `Editor` that will be the "*Creator*" of the posts.

**The "*Creator*" will write the posts, save them as `Draft` and then the "*Supervisor*" will, at a later time, review them and decide for whatever action needs to be taken**.

---

### The steps:

From your writings I assume that your organization created the Facebook page, which makes them the "*Owner*" as well as the `Admin`.
Then, you were later assigned as the PAO granting you permission to write the posts that go online. This makes you an  `Admin` as well or an `Editor` (depending on the "*Page Role*" you were granted for the specific page).

### Step 1: Create a draft of a post for the Facebook Page:

- At the top of your Page's Timeline, click the type of post you want to create
- Add details to your post
- Click the little arrow next to `Publish`
- Select `Save Draft`

[image: Save Draft]

You will get a post on your page informing you of the created draft.
[image: draft on page]

**Please note**: If you have more than one drafts they will be "*bundled*" together to just one draft post.
[image: many drafts on page]

Your job as the "*Creator*" of the post is done.

### Step 2: The *Admin* of the page wishes to review/publish the post:

- The `Admin` logs-in under the organization's account.
- To see your drafts, will then need to click on `Publishing Tools` at the top of the Page,
- Click `Drafts` in the left column
  **Or simply click the `See drafts` link on the above mentioned post**.

This will bring up the Drafts screen:
[image: drafts screen]

The `Admin`can click on any draft and review it.
After reviewing the post/s can now:

- `Edit` or
- `Publish` (approve) the draft/s you've created,
- `Schedule`,
- `Backdate` or simply
- `Delete` it/them by clicking the appropriate link.

[image: admin approval]

Draft posts can be edited and re-edited, saved and re-saved as many times as you like.

**Following the above steps does not require any special coding or actions. Just an understanding between the involved parties of the organization**.

---

As mentioned before I assume there are at least two unique accounts for the page.
If -for some reason- the structure of your organization is different or you need to edit a role or even assign a new one for your page (you may want to have more than one `Editor` for when one is on leave) you should use the "*Page Role*" screen under `Settings`:

[image: Page Roles screen]

Here is a table you could consult about each Role's permissions:
[image: Role permissions]

**References at the Facebook Help Center**:
[How do I create a draft of a post for my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/642707099175171)
[How do I edit or publish drafts for my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/792027744168909)
[What are the different Page roles and what can they do?](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410)
[How do I give someone a role on my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/187316341316631)

Comment: So far, this seems to be the closest to what I'm wanting. You're right about multiple accounts. The only improvement would be if Facebook had a role that allowed saving drafts, but not publishing them. Which they don't.

Comment: @cullub I believe it is the simplest solution If I were you I would also consider adding an extra `Editor` for the page. It makes life so much easier. As far as the bounty goes, I would leave it on as well. Although you can always un-accept the answer, it is still on for another 5 days.